# tar command generates error in shell script

Tags: shell-script, filenames, tar

I am trying to create a tar ball in a shell script (I have enabled `set -x`), but I get the following error:

```
+ cd /home5/mysite/public_html
+ TAR_DUMP=gypo_2012-02-18-03:51:15.tar.gz
+ echo 'Tar name: gypo_2012-02-18-03:51:15.tar.gz'
Tar name: gypo_2012-02-18-03:51:15.tar.gz
+ tar -cvzf gypo_2012-02-18-03:51:15.tar.gz gypo
...
tar: gypo_2012-02-18-03\:44\:04.tar.gz: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
...
```

The script is:

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")

# TAR

cd $HOME/public_html
TAR_DUMP="gypo_$NOW.tar.gz"
echo "Tar name: $TAR_DUMP"
tar -cvzf $TAR_DUMP gypo
# mv -t $DEST $TAR_DUMP
```

Why is tar generating this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:` in the filename are confusing  `tar`. At least for the `coreutils` version of `tar`, the `--file` switch can take an argument of the form:

```
hostname:/remote/file/name
```

so I'm guessing `tar` is trying to interpret that filename in a manner that is not what you meant.

Prefixing the file name with `./` (or specifying a full path) should solve your problem.

```
TAR_DUMP="./gypo_$NOW.tar.gz"
echo "Tar name: $TAR_DUMP"
tar -cvzf $TAR_DUMP gypo
```

Another fix would be to add the `--force-local` switch.

> `--force-local`
>
> Forces `tar' to interpret the filename given to --file as a local
>        file, even if it looks like a remote tape drive name.

Comment: Adding ./ solved the issue, many many thanks !!!